# Bing Maps get routepath coordinates of locations that fall on that route on a predefined distance interval

Tags: javascript, html, rest, bing-maps

when we request this url http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0=Minneapolis,MN&wp.1=St%20Paul,MN&optmz=distance&routeAttributes=routePath&key=BingMapsKey it gives a JSON response which includes routePath coordinates but they are not on regular interval.Is it possible to get the coordinates of the location which fall on route with fixed interval of distance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to have the route path coordinates spread out in an regular interval. Note that if it did the route response would either be a lot bigger, or would be much less accurate. Note that it isn't overly difficult to calculate coordinates along a route/line. I have a good example of how to do this in the path animation module I created a while ago here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#BMv7Plugins/BMv7.AnimationModule/js/AnimationModule.js